# Overwrite and append in existing file

Tags: java, file, filewriter

How to ovewrite existing file and then appending on it.

```
BufferedWriter outStream= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("encoded.txt", true));
```

It just append lines in it.

I want whenever `outStream` gets created, it overwrite the existing file then keep appending until the code is finished.

Any idea how to perform this action ?

Comment: Set append to `false`!

Comment: If you want to overwrite a file, then instead of doing "new FileWriter("encoded.txt", true)", do "new FileWriter("encoded.txt", false)"

Comment: cant both steps done in done one ?

Comment: You might use Files.newBufferedWriter​(Path path, OpenOption... options) and set the options to your heart's content.

Comment: @linus once you've created your FileWriter, just writer as much data to it as you like. The old file is gone. There is no separate 'append' step.